# databind textbox to a member of an object which in turn is the member of some other object, list of which is the data source

Tags: c#, data-binding, textbox

```
.
.
List<DailyEntry> dailyEntries = BAL.getDailyEntriesToBind();

txtSite.DataBindings.Add("Text", dailyEntries, "SiteName");
.
dataRepeater1.DataSource = dailyEntries;
.
.
```

where `DailyEntry` and `Site` are

```
class DailyEntry
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get;set; }
    public Site Site { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
class Site
{
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
}
```

now txtSite is not getting the value.

I know its because `SiteName` is not a direct member of `DailyEntry`.. I also tried with `Site.SiteName` as datamember for `Textbox.Databindings.Add` method, it didn't work

actually the text box I want to bind to, resides on a datarepeater. so I can't use like `dailyEntries[0].Site` as dataSource for `Textbox.Databindings.Add` method

what is the solution?

**EDIT:**
I also tried by overriding `toString()` method for `Site` class as follows

```
class Site
{
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return SiteName;
    }
}
```

Comment: try DataBindings.Add("Text", dailyEntries.Select(x => x.Site.SiteName), "SiteName")